# Web config rewrite rule not displaying correct page

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5, mediawiki

I'm trying to rewrite a url in a Mediawiki site, and everything looks to be working according to failed request log files output. Yet the page being displayed is the original page, and not the url in the rewrite.  Basically I want 
 
 
`www.website.com/State/City/Category` 
 to show the page at 
`www.website.com/index.php?title=Special:RunQuery/CategoryPage&CategoryPage[State]=
State&CategoryPage[City]=City&CategoryPage[Category]=Category&wpRunQuery=true` 

instead it seems to be showing the page at 
`www.website.com/index.php?title=State/City/Category`
printing _SERVER shows QUERY_STRING as the Special:RunQuery page, but otherwise all other variables show index.php or /State/City/Category.  My web.config Rewrite rules look like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?title=Main_Page" />
        </rule>
       <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^index\.php$" />
           <conditions>
               <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" />
               <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
       </rule>
       <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyCategoryURL" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?title=Special:RunQuery/CategoryPage&amp;CategoryPage[State]={UrlDecode:{R:1}}&amp;CategoryPage[City]={UrlDecode:{R:2}}&amp;CategoryPage[Category]={UrlDecode:{R:3}}&amp;wpRunQuery=true" />
        </rule>
       <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(.+)$" />
           <conditions>
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?title={UrlDecode:{R:1}}" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Appreciate any help in figuring this one out.  Been racking my brain for 2 days now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your rules locally and they worked as you indicated, request:
Testing:
RequestURL="/State/City/Category"

will correctly rewrite it to:
"localhost:80/index.php?title=Special:RunQuery/CategoryPage&CategoryPage[State]=State&CategoryPage[City]=City&CategoryPage[Category]=Category&wpRunQuery=true"

My recommendation would be to use Failed Request Tracing: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules
and that should tell you exactly what is happening.

Comment: Appreciate you checking it out.  I tried Failed Request Tracing, and like I said above, everything appears ok.  Towards the end of the log it does a rewrite action that looks good, rule evaluation shows the new query string, rewrite end shows a request url of index.php, then it makes requests to the full correct string, and then ends with a 200 success.  What I'm wondering is maybe Mediawiki is looking at something else and serving a different page based on other variables.  Request_URI is still set to /State/City/Category.  Can you alter Request_URI and other _Server variables in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured since Carlos said the web.config looked good, it must be Mediawiki, and sure enough I found a place where it checks for and uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].  This might be changed on URL Rewrite for Apache, but it isn't in IIS.  Luckily I managed to fix it with a change in LocalSettings.php, so yay for no mods to the core code.  So if anyone else has this problem with IIS and Mediawiki, or IIS and any other PHP Apache centric site, you can add this code below:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```